# Head function doesn't work - R

Tags: r, sorting, indexing, head

I've got the following command:

```
temp <- sort(menVSwomen,decreasing = FALSE, index.return=TRUE)
```

temp now contains 10000 indexes, resulting from the sorting of menVSwomen. I am trying to extract the top 100 using `head(temp, 100)` but that won't work?! To my surprise it returns the whole vector.
What is going on?

Note that I also tried `head(as.vector(temp),100)` also using `n=100` but it still returns the entire temp. Help!

As you probably have guessed I am trying to get the indexes of the 100 lowest values in the menVSwomen vector. If there's an other way around my problem, please share your opinion.

This is an output of str(temp):

```
List of 2
$ x : Named num [1:10000] 0.000176 0.000249 0.000412 0.000575 0.000604 ...
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10000] "1542" "2693" "4840" "3329" ...
$ ix: int [1:10000] 1542 2693 4840 3329 5257 5292 8844 8368 2082 8486 ...
```

Comment: What is the `str()` for `temp`?

Comment: @CephBirk Just edited my question after your request.

Comment: You probably want `lapply(temp, head, 100)` since temp is a list.  Calling `head` on a list returns, by default, the first 6 list elements.  Hence the whole list since you only have two elements

Comment: Depending on what you want to observe, take a look at `cgwtools::short`  ( https://github.com/cellocgw/cgwtools_rev2 ) I deliberately `unlist` list variables, but that will return the first N elements, not limited to a specific list element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem originates from what the sort function returns. If you take a look at `str(temp)` output,sort returns a list of 2! I just need what's in $ix .
The workaround I used is simple:

```
head(temp$ix,n=100)
```

Credit also goes to @CephBirk

Comment: This is more user-error than something worth rep. Learn what a 'list' is.